# Reduction of Order Differential Equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have a diff eq such as $x^3y^{''}-5y=0$, given $y_1 = x^4$ I wish to solve this equation using Abel's theorem and reduction of order, and the Wronskian. The only issue is, Abel's theorem states that $W[y_1,y_2] = y_1y_2^{'}-y_1^{'}y_2 = Ce^{\int p(x) dx}$ for an equation of the form $y^{''}+p(x)y^{'}+q(x)y = 0$.

The only issue is, there's no $p(x)$. so what does one do?

Comment: $x^2 y'' - 2y = x^2 y'' + 0y' - 2y$.

Comment: @T.Bongers This leads to a solution of $y = Dx^2 - Cx$, which is not the solution.

Comment: I tried setting $W[y_1,y_2] = C$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the other solution can be written as a multiple of $y_1$, so that $y_2 = x^2 v$ for a function $v(x)$. Using

$$y'' = \frac{2}{x^2} y$$

and the product rule a few times, we'll eventually get to

$$2v + 2xv' + 2xv' + x^2 v'' = 2v \implies 4v' + x v'' = 0$$

Making the substitution $u = v'$, we're left with the first-order separable equation

$$\frac{u'}{u} = -\frac 4 x$$

which can be solved with elementary techniques.

---

Following this backwards through the substitutions, you should get (up to constants)

> $u$ is a multiple of $x^{-4}$; integrating and substituting for $v$, $y_2 = \frac 1 x$.

Comment: if you integrate $x^{-4}$, you get $-\frac{1}{3x^3}$. giving $y_2(t) = -\frac{1}{3x}$

Comment: Right: Up to a constant, it's $1/x$ (and the general solution is $y_2(x) = c x^{-1}$).

Comment: good, this is what I did before, just confirming